# COCOEval get 0 result for AP and AR?

Tags: python, pytorch, coco

I am trying to do project in detecting keypoints from images. For the evaluation, I am using COCOeval to calculate the AP and AR. However, the evaluation dataset always get result 0 for all AP and AR. Is it normal for early stage of the training where the prediction still very bad? or There is something wrong with the code.

Here the validation result example:

[
{
"category_id": 1,
"center": [
138.40066528320312,
120.2301254272461
],
"image_id": 100000,
"scale": [
1.2766542434692383,
1.2766542434692383
],
"score": 1.0,
"keypoints": [
369.5614013671875,
7.676669120788574,
1.0,
416.5087890625,
24.127635955810547,
1.0,
491.8260498046875,
31.30722427368164,
1.0,
335.75958251953125,
30.002338409423828,
1.0,
353.5982666015625,
60.155391693115234,
1.0,
472.4736328125,
41.874290466308594,
1.0,
210.8014373779297,
28.03527069091797,
1.0,
457.08782958984375,
-108.73526000976562,
1.0,
543.10205078125,
-105.9140396118164,
1.0,
343.39666748046875,
5.00376033782959,
1.0,
595.7027587890625,
-97.80133819580078,
1.0,
434.21527099609375,
-67.6851577758789,
1.0,
204.2008819580078,
35.23044204711914,
1.0,
235.04319763183594,
21.53371810913086,
1.0
]
},

and here is the ground truth for the same input:

"annotations": [
{
"num_keypoints": 14,
"area": 5953.55502952497,
"iscrowd": 0,
"keypoints": [
131.5449676513672,
117.83085632324219,
2.0,
130.82444763183594,
159.96043395996094,
2.0,
130.6156463623047,
202.69972229003906,
2.0,
149.73643493652344,
117.50897216796875,
2.0,
146.06874084472656,
159.61378479003906,
2.0,
144.61448669433594,
202.6561737060547,
2.0,
140.7966766357422,
46.8616943359375,
2.0,
141.01756286621094,
20.056594848632812,
2.0,
160.11976623535156,
60.10404968261719,
2.0,
163.0663299560547,
91.96377563476562,
2.0,
163.53526306152344,
120.45011901855469,
2.0,
121.48643493652344,
59.48382568359375,
2.0,
116.56602478027344,
90.03926086425781,
2.0,
116.50920104980469,
118.90538024902344,
2.0
],
"image_id": 100000,
"bbox": [
109.25439453125,
18.0977840423584,
58.29255676269531,
204.26467323303223
],
"category_id": 1,
"id": 100000
},

and here is the result:
[image: result]